# Bootstrap Dropdown won't trigger click event

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap dropdown my problem is that the click event will not trigger. Why is the click event won't trigger? and is there a way to fix this?

```
<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
  <button type="button" class="btn header-item noti-icon waves-effect" id="page-header-notifications-dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <i class="bx bx-bell"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-end p-0" aria-labelledby="page-header-notifications-dropdown">
      <div class="p-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col">
               <h6 class="m-0" key="t-notifications"> Notifications
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>       
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my click event:

```
$(document).on('click','#page-header-notifications-dropdown',function() {
    alert();
});
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap and jquery are you using?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Bootstrap v5.0.0

Comment: It works though https://jsfiddle.net/rsgv87mx/1/

Comment: ^ as long as you include jquery for how you added a click event

Comment: @Samathingamajig I updated the version of Bootstrap and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is your click event

Try this and see if it works. when i copied the code into VS code the alert popped up.

```
document.getElementById('page-header-notifications-dropdown').onclick = function() {
    alert();
};
```